# Topological decomposition of a smooth manifold

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds, polytopes

The decomposition of a smooth manifold for topological analysis requires that all vertices lie at the ends of edges, all edges bound the incident faces, and so on. Thus for example a decomposition of the sphere must be a graph.
But I am unable to find a generic name for this kind of decomposition in *n* dimensions. Incidence complexes, CW complexes and so on seem to be more general constructs which apply to other kinds of object. On the other hand simplicial complexes are over-specific, as the elements need only be simple (i.e. topological balls) and not specifically simplices.
Is there a specific term for such a decomposition of a manifold into simple elements, such that there are no rogue vertices, etc?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(topology)#Explicit_methods_of_triangulation).

Comment: A triangle is a simplex. I explain in my question that "the elements need only be simple (e.g. convex) and not specifically simplices". But thanks for trying.

Comment: That quote you have emphasized from your post doesn't help much: you have not defined what you mean by "simple", and "convex" is not a defined concept in the theory of smooth manifolds.

Comment: Another possibility is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex#Regular_CW_complexes).

Comment: Thanks again, but as I explain in my question, "CW complexes and so on seem to be more general constructs which apply to other kinds of object". Specifically, a CW complex need not conform to the abstract "diamond condition" which all polytopes exhibit.

Comment: So did you intend to include into your question some kind of requirement that every cell be a polytope? If that's the case, you should add that to your question, because it is not specified.

Comment: @LeeMosher I did define "simple" but have now made that clearer and removed convexity. For your part, you need to define a "polytope" in the context of topological decomposition before I can answer you.

Comment: You brought up to term "polytope" in your comment, so I'll leave it to you to decide what its role is in your question.

Comment: Then let's say that not all CW complexes are decompositions of smooth manifolds. The article you linked to gave polytopes as an example of CW complexes, which was why I picked up on it, but we can let that whole polytope thing pass.

Comment: So then I go back to my suggestion of a "regular CW complex" in my second link. One can formulate a very broad definition of CW complex, certainly much too broad, as you say. One can then formulate the more narrow concept of a regular CW complex, still too broad. But then one states Whitehead's theorem: every smooth manifold can be given the structure of a regular CW complex. After that, one can *prove* additional properties that will hold for any regular CW complex on a smooth manifold, e.g. a property which one might wish to formulate as "no rogue vertices".

Comment: That would not answer your question about a "specific term", and I think there is no such term. But, it would answer the underlying mathematical question regarding what kinds of interesting topological decompositions exist for manifolds?

Comment: Indeed, your suggestion seems basically "A CW complex of a certain kind". This was pretty much the position which prompted me to ask. Polytopes, tilings and graphs are all examples of what I am after but a definitive term seems elusive.